# How does CRSF LazyCsrfTokenRepository work?

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

Java 8 - spring 4.3.x

While configuring spring security and enable csrf feature i came across two implementations of `CsrfTokenRepository` one is Lazy another is Cookie based

I know `CookieCsrfTokenRepository` works using writing a csrf token into cookie and accepts a cookie value in header to verify the valid request

Can some one help me to understand how does `LazyCsrfTokenRepository` works ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/LazyCsrfTokenRepository.html):

> A `CsrfTokenRepository` that delays saving new `CsrfToken` until the
>   attributes of the `CsrfToken` that were generated are accessed.

**So why this?** In earlier versions of Spring Security the `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository` was default. The drawback with this was that it always creates a token, triggering session creation, regardless of whether the token was used or not, which could be wasteful in some applications.

The `LazyCsrfTokenRepository` on the other hand only creates a wrapper, and creates the actual token only if `getToken()` is invoked (like when for example generating a form). This avoids unnecessary session creation.

A gotcha with `LazyCsrfTokenRepository` is that the actual token generation must still happen before HTTP response is *committed*, otherwise you get an exception. If you get problem with this, it is easiest to use (only) one of the other two implementations.