# Disable JSESSIONID conditionally in Spring-Boot-Web / Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm trying to disable the creation of the `JSESSIONID` Cookie conditionally.

I only want to create this cookie if a certain cookie in the request is present.

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-web` `2.5.3` with `spring-boot-starter-security`.

## What I've tried so far

### Spring-Session -> CookieSerializer Bean

I tried to add `spring-session` and define a custom `DefaultCookieSerializer`-Bean. It turned out that the `JSESSIONID` is not actually coming from spring, but from the underlying Tomcat.

### Using a `javax.servlet.Filter` which blocks setting the `Set-Cookie` Header:

```java
package xxxx.configuration;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@Configuration
public class CookieConsentConfiguration {

    private static class CookieConsentFilter implements Filter {

        private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        private CookieConsentFilter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

            if (hasCookieConsent(req)) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, new NoCookiesResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response));
            }
        }

        private boolean hasCookieConsent(HttpServletRequest request) {
            try {
                final Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
                if (cookies != null) {
                    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                        if (cookie.getName().equals("cookie_consent_level")) {
                            final String value = cookie.getValue();
                            final JsonNode json = this.objectMapper.readTree(URLDecoder.decode(value, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));

                            return json.hasNonNull("strictly-necessary") && json.get("strictly-necessary").booleanValue();
                        } else if (cookie.getName().equals("cookie_consent_user_accepted")) {
                            return Boolean.parseBoolean(cookie.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    private static class NoCookiesResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

        public NoCookiesResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
            super(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
            // not allowed
        }

        @Override
        public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
            if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("set-cookie")) {
                super.setHeader(name, value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
            if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("set-cookie")) {
                super.addHeader(name, value);
            }
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter cookieConsentFilter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new CookieConsentFilter(objectMapper);
    }
}
```

But this also didn't work. The `JSESSIONID` is still being created.

Is there any way to disable the creation of this (or any) Cookie if some conditions aren't met?

Comment: If you are using sessions for any valid reason at all (such as logins), the session cookie is the most strictly necessary of all.

Comment: I know, and I have a login. But the Session-Cookie is created right on the first visit on the page, without an attempt to login at all. 
Also, I've set the SessionCreationPolicy to IF_REQUIRED.
Are the CSRF Values also remembered on the server side using the session? Could those be the reason the session is created?

Comment: By default `LazyCsrfTokenRepository` is used (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49057057/11748454)), so no session is generated **unless** you use the token. Can you provide a minimal example of page which causes problems?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I used the `csrf` token in every of my thymeleaf templates. That forced the session to be created

Comment: @Felix: can you write an answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

###### Disclaimer: This answer does not directly answer the question, how to stop creating a JSESSIONID based on a condition. I'll not accept this answer for this reason.

---

#### GDPR

I found out that Strictly necessary cookies are allowed by default, without a requirement to show the user a cookie-layer *before* sending the cookie to the client. As I understand, you still have to display the cookie-layer to the user at the very first page impression.

That essentially means, to my understanding, that you are allowed to send `Set-Cookie`-Headers for Strictly necessary cookies on the users first page load. On that page, the cookie-layer has to be shown, but Strictly necessary cookies may already exists at that point.

For more information, see: https://gdpr.eu/cookies/

---

#### Technical stuff

##### General

First of all, we have to understand under what circumstances a `JSESSIONID` is created.

It is created whenever some piece of code tries to obtain a session from the application server. That means, if we can structure our code in a way that it doesn't try to obtain a session from the application server, no `JSESSIONID`-Cookie will be sent to the client.

But there are a few pitfalls. For some things, a session is the most necessary cookie of all:

- Login: A login (as in human-user-login on a website), strictly requires a session
- CSRF-Tokens: The server needs something to obtain these Tokens from. It's the session
- ... more

##### Example with Spring-Boot

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-web` in Version `2.5.3`. I want a session to be only created if it's truly required, for one of the reasons I mentioned above: The users tries to login or the users accesses a site that requires CSRF Tokens to be created for security reasons.

The first relevant config can be found in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:
Setting the `SessionCreationPolicy` to `IF_REQUIRED`.

```java
    @Configuration
    public static class GlobalWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/css/**", "/js/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf()
                        .and()
                    .headers()
                        .frameOptions()
                        .deny()
                        .and()
                    .sessionManagement()// these two lines
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                        .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                        .and()
                    .logout()
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }
    }
```

The second relevant thing in my case was to only embed the `CSRF`-Tokens if they're truly required for the page.

I had a couple of thymeleaf templates of which I always used the same `<head>` Section. In every of my templates, my `<head>` Section included the following lines:

```html
    <meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

While this is still required for pages that perform `POST`, `PUT`, ... - Requests to my server, it is not required for most of my pages.

I removed the use of the `CSRF`-Token in every thymeleaf template where it was not required.

Now, a session is only obtained (and a `JSESSIONID` is created) from the application server once the user tries to access a page that includes a `CSRF`-Token